# Can't access DynamoDB from a Lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, amazon-lightsail

I have a Lightsail instance running a simple PHP web portal, and need to access some tables in DynamoDB. If I try using the AWS SDK directly:

```
$sdk = new Sdk([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'ap-southeast-2'
]);

$db_client = $sdk->createDynamoDb()
```

then I get an access denied error when I make a query:

```
AccessDeniedException (client): User: arn:aws:sts::xyz:assumed-role/AmazonLightsailInstanceRole/i-xyz is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:xyz:table/tablename
```

I created an additional IAM role with DynamoDB permissions, but Lightsail isn't listed as a service that I can attach the role to. Nor am I able to see any place on the Lightsail console to attach an IAM role anyway. Additionally, all the docs that I see tell me that you can't modify Lightsail's inbuilt IAM role.

What I **am** able to do is set up AWS CLI on my Lightsail instance and add my security keys, then I can access DynamoDB from the CLI on my instance. However I have no idea how to let my code use these credentials (I've seen that you can add the credentials in the SDK config, but I obviously don't want my credentials in code. It should look for them in my instance's environment variables, however, and they are definitely there).

Lightsail advertises DynamoDB integration so I know it should work, but I've been pulling my hair out trying to get access. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the EC2 role `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` have permission to access DynamoDB?

Comment: I can't see that role in the IAM console. The only three roles I had are auto-generated, Service-Linked roles called `AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable`, `AWSServiceRoleForSupport`, and `AWSServiceRoleForTrustedAdvisor`. The fourth role I created is for an EC2 instance but again, I can't see a place to attach it to my Lightsail instance.

Comment: check the exception you stated in the question, ad well see what role is really attached to the instance

Comment: Solved it without bothering with roles. Cheers anyway.

Comment: AWS LightSail instances have IAM roles assigned to them by AWS that you cannot change. You have to use a different method of authentication, such as environment variables, or a credentials file.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get my code to use my AWS CLI credentials in the end. Here's how I solved it.

1. In code, specified a CredentialProvider so that it would try and use my CLI credentials, rather than defaulting to the IAM role (or I assume this is what it did anyway). Note the `ini` type to force it to look for a credentials file:

```
use Aws\Sdk;
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;

$provider = CredentialProvider::ini();

$sdk = new Sdk([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'ap-southeast-2'
    'credentials' => $provider
]);

$db_client = $sdk->createDynamoDb()
```

2. Ensured that my credentials were in my `~/.aws/credentials` file.
3. After this, I would get a different error:

```
CredentialsException: Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials
```

Note that it specified the `.aws` directory was located in `/`, not `~/`.

4. Copied my `.aws` directory to `/`. *Made sure set read permissions with `chmod`*
5. Success.

Hopefully this helps someone else use this godforsaken service which Amazon has  seemingly released without proper documentation.